# How to get unread message from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Messages are broadcast to users. So creating only one record of message in updates table.

```
table name : updates
id : 
title : message
user_id : created user id

table name : message _status
id
message_id
user_id : read by user
```

If any user read message we make entry in updates_status table.

I want to show list of unread message those are not created by current user and unread. Here is my query:

```
select u.*, s.user_id as status_user, s.id 
 from updates as u left outer join update_status as s ON u.id=s.update_id 
 where u.user_id != 1 and (s.user_id is null or s.user_id  != 1)
```

I am getting 6 records instead of 5.

Here is the DDL from the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b2ccf/2/0):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `u_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `users`
--

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `u_name`) VALUES
(1, 'Praveen'),
(2, 'Ravi'),
(3, 'Ram'),
(4, 'Mohan');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `updates` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `updates`
--

INSERT INTO `updates` (`id`, `title`, `user_id`, `created`) VALUES
(1, 'message1', 2, '2015-09-28 15:50:38'),
(2, 'message2', 2, '2015-09-28 15:50:38'),
(3, 'message3', 1, '2015-09-28 17:00:37'),
(4, 'message4', 1, '2015-09-28 17:00:37'),
(5, 'message5', 3, '2015-09-28 17:05:21'),
(6, 'message6', 4, '2015-09-28 17:05:21');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `update_status` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `update_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `update_status`
--

INSERT INTO `update_status` (`id`, `update_id`, `user_id`, `created`) VALUES
(2, 1, 1, '2015-09-28 17:02:15'),
(3, 3, 2, '2015-09-28 17:04:16'),
(4, 1, 3, '2015-09-28 17:06:24'),
(5, 1, 4, '2015-09-28 17:06:33'),
(6, 3, 3, '2015-09-28 17:17:12');
```

Comment: I want to get unread messages for current user.

Comment: please post how your final result should be from those values you posted in question?

Comment: I want update.id, update.title and username who created this message

Answer (score 3):

**Changed to exclude users own updates**

```
SELECT Updates.id 
FROM Updates 
JOIN Users 
ON Updates.user_id != Users.id and Users.id = 1 -- CURRENT USER ID
LEFT JOIN Update_status 
ON Users.id = update_status.user_id 
and updates.id = update_status.id 
WHERE update_status.created is null 
ORDER BY updates.created desc
```

returns

```
id
--
5
6
1
```

Comment: I didn't understand here 3, 4 line. It should exclude message created by current user.

Comment: SELECT Updates.*,Users.u_name FROM Updates JOIN Users ON Updates.user_id = Users.id and Users.id != 3 LEFT JOIN Update_status ON updates.id = update_status.id WHERE update_status.created is null OR update_status.user_id != 3 ORDER BY updates.created desc this gives correct result . But I want to skip the mesages those I allready read.

Comment: In your result one should be skippe ,because it is allready read.

Comment: What are you looking to return in your query as you seem to have changed the query to look at all users but not user 3 and not return if user 3 has read something, this confuses me as in my query just change the user.id = 1 to user.id = 3 to return user 3's unread messages.

Comment: In Update_status table i am storing message id with user_id who has read. In result I want to show list of messages sent from other and not read by user (ex: userid =1)